# listitem states not working using with navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using Navigation Drawer for my android application.I am using a listview for showing the items in navigation drawer.I want to use Listitem state color for listview, but its not working and not showing different color for different states.My code is:

**navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_item_selector"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/side_navigation_list_divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**navigation_item_selector.xml**

```
    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray_back" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_activated ="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abs__ab_solid_light_holo"/>

</selector>
```